# Images with border not for all nodes in Vis.js

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

I search for an option to use the VisJS network graph with the option images with borders like in this example :

http://visjs.org/examples/network/nodeStyles/imagesWithBorders.html

But not for all images.

I try to append the settings for the node that should get the border like this

```
 if(some expression){
        aService.shapeProperties = {useBorderWithImage:true};
        aService.nodes =  {
            borderWidth:100,
                size:50,
                color: {
                border: '#ff0000',
                    background: '#ff0000'
            },
            shapeProperties: {
                useBorderWithImage:true
            }
        };
    }
```

but this is ignored.

How can I do it right ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the node options directly at node creation time? For example:

```
var nodes = new vis.DataSet();
var visNode = {id: 123, shape: 'image', image: 'person.png', borderWidth:    5, shapeProperties: { useBorderWithImage:true} };

nodes.update([visNode]);
```

Although I have not done this on an individual node myself, I imagine it would work. BTW, note that a borderWidth of 100 might be too large a border. You might want to try with a small number first -e.g. 5-, and then increase it as needed.